# The seen from IP address logging seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, ip-address

The "seen from" IP address, which logs the last IP user has been seen at seems to be broken; seems to be showing many users for the IP address of stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.44).

Example:

https://superuser.com/admin/users-with-ip/198.252.206.44

We've had 2 separate bug reports on this:

- [why is it telling me always "You can only post once every 5 minutes."](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7746/why-is-it-telling-me-always-you-can-only-post-once-every-5-minutes#comment9_7746?noredirect=1)
- [Submit button not working](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7744/submit-button-not-working)

Comment: Is `users-with-ip` some kind of moderators-only address? It looks broken (404) for me.

Comment: @Mołot: Yes, it's a mod tool.

Comment: @Molot the URL contains *admin*.

Comment: @Mołot and the question is tagged [meta-tag:moderator-tools] too. (agree that without it, it could be confusing)

Comment: No repro on UX.SE (for that IP address anyway).

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question, if I misunderstood please revert it. Also, I get 198.252.206.140 for stackoverflow.com, but that could be load balancing or whatever.

Comment: strange this, this seems to be limited to [su]

Comment: @JonW hey did you steal [Ben Collins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136973/ben-collins)'s avatar? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have "access to moderator tools" privilege on Drupal Answers and it's 404 for me there, too, so this tag is not enough. How did I manage to overlook `admin` part is another story.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: We bare-knuckle-boxed for it. I won so I got to keep the coloured version.

Comment: @Mołot the URL requires you to be a Diamond Moderator - not a 10k+ user

Comment: @Sathya yea, I got it, see my previous (second-last now) comment.

Comment: @Mołot The [tag:moderator-tools] tag is for diamond-moderator tools only, it should not be used for 10k tools anyway.

Comment: @MadScientist gotta love using the same name for different tools on one site...

Comment: I am constructing a fix for this, needless to say it needs a lot of testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with an additional accelerator proxy placed in front of Super User specifically.  The additional headers were not expected by a bit of the remote IP code which has just been corrected.  IPs will correct themselves as people keep using the site today.