# Seen from IP is reporting that users are from Cloudflare's network

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, ip-address

This is similar to [The seen from IP address logging seems to be broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223145/the-seen-from-ip-address-logging-seems-to-be-broken)

In the linked question, I had mentioned

> The "seen from" IP address, which logs the last IP user has been seen at seems to be broken; seems to be showing many users for the IP address of stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.44).

while now, it seems to be showing many users to be coming from [Cloudflare's network](http://whois.domaintools.com/141.101.98.79).

and with the recent spam hobbling mechanism, few spam flags here and there could result in many legit users getting blocked out.

This is behaviour seems to be specific to Super User, over at Web Apps, the last seen from IP is correct.

---

I notice that this [behaviour is back again](https://superuser.com/admin/users-with-ip/103.31.5.6). Can you all at least give a heads-up on when this is going to happen? Reporting hundreds of users of coming from the same IP is a huge pain when it comes to user analysis

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the remnants of an experiment we conducted, but we're not doing it any longer. This was a very short, narrowly-scoped test.

It all revolves around site reliability / stability, and various options open to us when it comes to that. You'll see it for a bit longer, but those are just remnants as I mentioned.

Comment: Does this mean you guys are no longer considering using CloudFlare on Stack Exchange?

Comment: It seems this behaviour is back again. Are you folks resuming the experiments?